# Image not getting uploaded in directory

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image

I have an option to upload images with caption for every table and there can be any number of tables.

I am using the script below but alert('qwert') does not popup but instead alert('asdf') popsup.Any ideas?

PHP file1:

```
<form  method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' class='MyUploadForm'>
                    <input name='ImageFile' class='imageInput' id='imageInput' type='file'>
                    <input class='form-control dsa addcaption' name='addcaption' placeholder='Add caption' type='text' >
                    <input type='submit'  class='btn-custom5' value='Upload' >
                    <button class='btn btn-custom4 imageuploading' name='imageuploading' style='visibility:hidden' value='$x' ></button>//$x will specify path
                    </form>
                    <div class='output'></div>
```

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
            target:   '.output',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
            beforeSubmit:  beforeSubmit,  // pre-submit callback 
            success:       afterSuccess,  // post-submit callback 
            resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 
        }; 

     $('.MyUploadForm').submit(function() { 
            $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
            return false; 
        }); 

}); 


function beforeSubmit(){
 alert('qwert');
//code to check conditions for file type and size
}
```

PHP file2:

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
    //check if this is an ajax request
    if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])){
        die("<script> alert('asdf')</script>");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't upload images via Ajax directly

Comment: I have used the script above to upload images for non-dynamic content and without caption and it was working.

Comment: `$('.MyUploadForm').submit(function()..` means "after submitting, do this". The form is submitted before the AJAX call is made.

Comment: the problem persists...plus .btn-custom5 already has type='submit'

Comment: @afaolek I have used the script above to upload images for non-dynamic content and without caption and it was working

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: What is it you intend to do in the beforeSubmit function?

Comment: @beingalex check file size and type and alert the user accordingly

Comment: afterSuccess is undefined! It will never do an ajaxSubmit, but just a normal submit

Comment: @afaolek is right, you're triggering an submit, so you will never have an ajax submit

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var request = $.ajax({
    url: $('.MyUploadForm').attr('action'),
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    target:   '.output',   // (Not sure about this) target element(s) to be updated with server response
    beforeSend:  beforeSubmit,  // pre-submit callback 
    success:       afterSuccess,  // post-submit callback 
    resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 
}); 

function beforeSubmit(){
   alert('qwert');
   //code to check conditions for file type and size
}
```

Hopefully, I'm right. You can check the [jQuery.ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more.

EDIT:

I'm not sure about `target`. Maybe you should set the targets in `success` callback.

Comment: no..it is not working...can you suggest some other way to call via ajax such that the data(image+caption+path(that cant be edited by user)) is passed to PHP file2 and I can check certain conditions in beforeSubmit()

Comment: What is not working? Images are not getting uploaded or you don't see the `alert` box?

Comment: Images are not getting uploaded and alert('asdf') pops up instead of alert('qwert');

Comment: What browser are you using? I just read from this [link](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax) that not all browsers support `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a plugin. Are you sure you have installed [this](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin in your page?

If yes, You cannot trigger the submit event in your form or your ajaxSubmit will never execute, check the button click instead...

Aditionally, Be sure you're providing a afterSuccess function :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
            target:   '.output',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
            beforeSubmit:  beforeSubmit,  // pre-submit callback 
            success:       afterSuccess,  // post-submit callback 
            resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 
        }; 

     $('.btn-custom5').click(function() { 
            $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
            return false; 
        }); 
    function beforeSubmit(){
     alert('qwert');
    }
    function afterSuccess(){
     alert('asdfg');
    }
});
```

If you're still getting errors after that, I suggest you to read the file upload examples in the [plugin homepage](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload)